# How to find and sum up all with the matching words on a list?

Tags: python, list

```
EmpRecords=[1,'Angelo','Fabregas','South','City',
           2,'Fabian','Fabregas','North','City',
           3,'Griffin','De Leon','West','City',
           4,'John','Doe','East','City',
           5,'Jane','Doe','Southville','Town']
```

Output should something be like:

```
Enter word to search: Doe
Same words: 2
```

How do I do this? I should also clarify that EmpRecords is actually just a text File that is converted into a list.

so it's actually:

```
EmpRecords='''1,Angelo,Fabregas,South,City;
           2,Fabian,Fabregas,North,City;
           3,Griffin,De Leon,West,City;
           4,John,Doe,East,City;
           5,Jane,Doe',Southville,Town'''
```

Maybe this has something to do with finding the matching words?

Comment: If you've got the list correctly, then just `EmpRecords.count('Doe')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to search for any word separated by comma and each line is a separate item:
Since your actual records are separated by ";" you need to create a nested list as below:

```
>>> record_groups = EmpRecords.split(";")
>>> final_groups = [each_group.split(",") for each_group in record_groups]
```

Later you can search through list items for the given word:

```
>>> word = "Doe"
>>> counter = 0
>>> for each_entry in final_groups:
        if word in each_entry:
            counter += 1        
>>> print(counter)
```

APPROACH 2:

If it is already in a file you can directly open line by line and search:

```
word = "Doe"
counter = 0
with open("input.txt") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if word in line.strip().split(",")
            counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: Hello, your code works wonders! however if I may ask, I changed word ="Doe" to City and all of the matching words with City and it does not show up?, is it because City isnt seperated by comma?

Comment: @GriffinDeLeon City should work too. Please share the code which you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read from the file and count, you can use a loop.

```
import csv
with open('records.txt') as csvfile:
    linereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    count = 0;
    target_value = 'Doe'
    for row in linereader:
        if row[2] == target_value:
            count += 1;

print("Count: ",count)
```

You may need to remove the semicolon (;) from the last field if you will be using the data.